# jQuery Validate number that is not required in Opera

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, validation, opera

I am writing a (localhost) website that is planned to be used in the Opera browser (since my site is using HTML5).  In part of the site I have a form and one of the fields is a number.  I am trying to use jQuery Validate plugin to validate that the entry is a number, but it is NOT required.

I expect this to be the solution, and it works in Chrome, but in Opera, the validation is ignored

```
<form id="productForm">
<input type="text" name="MinPrice" id="Minprice" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>​

$("#productForm").validate({
     rules: {
         MinPrice: {
             number: true
         }
     }
 });​
```

In order for jQuery to validate a number in Opera, it seems I must write:

```
<form id="productForm">
<input type="text" name="MinPrice" id="Minprice" />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>​

$("#productForm").validate({
     rules: {
         MinPrice: {
             number: true,
             required: true
         }
     }
 });​
```

But the problem is that I dont want to require MinPrice, I want to only validate it if I enter anything into the field

Thank you,

CampSoup1988

Comment: I guess type="number" confuses the jQuery plugin and makes it not run validation (unless the input is also required)? Can you write a small demo, for example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: [input type=number (does not work)](http://jsfiddle.net/xDsRD/) [input type=text (works)](http://jsfiddle.net/GCsTq/)

Comment: Please mark my answer as "accepted" with the green checkmark so that others with this problem can find the solution easily. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in the plugin (or in Opera depending on your point-of-view).

You may be able to work around it with a "dependency-callback" as follows:

```
$("#productForm").validate({
    rules: {
        MinPrice: {
            required: function(el) {
                var $el = $(el);
                if(!$el.val()) { $el.val('0') };
                return false;
            },
            number: true
        }
    }
});​
```

If I've got it right, then this should force the field never to be empty by inserting a '0'.

Providing the plugin performs its "required" validation before its number validation, this workaround stands a chance of working.

If it doesn't work, then you could achieve the same effect with a 'blur' handler bound to the field.

If you need distinguish between a user-entered '0' and the forced "fudge-value" then you could force '-1' instead of '0' and test server-side accordingly.

Comment: I changed one line to if(!$el.val()) { $el.val('') }; because I wanted the default to be null instead of zero, and your solution works as long as the input type is text, which I see I accidently wrote in my question, but I am using input type number, and it still not working for input type number.

Comment: Ah, HTML5 is a different matter entirely. Personally I would stick with `type="text"` and use the `pattern="regexp"` attribute to constrain what the use can enter and avoid needing to validate that field with the validation plugin, which clearly exhibits unreliable behaviour with `type="number"`.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens here is that in Opera, input.value (and what Opera submits) is an empty string if the typed value isn't a valid number. Somewhat confusingly, what the user typed is still left in the input without being flagged as invalid, and since .value is empty the JS validation doesn't see any problems either.

This is sort of correct according to [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), text "The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating point number, then set it to the empty string instead", but UI-wise it is still confusing so I think Opera should fix it.

Comment: So is there any way around this and still use the number input?  Or is there a way to make a text input work with the interface of a number input?

Comment: Short answer: no, as this is a problem you can not observe from JavaScript you can not work around it with JavaScript. IMO it's a small detail and you could decide to just wait for Opera's fix, if you're not happy with that, the "make default value 0 if input is empty (or contains a non-number value which JS can't observe but will be erased when we insert a 0)" approach might be best..